# How to add new vocab in SentenceTransformer

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, sentence-transformers

I am beginning my learning in NLP and I written the follow code for searching a similar text from my dataset by user input, which is mainly for some kind of recommendation system.

And the code is work but the result is not good when the user input a new word which is not in the model, for example `"Covid-19"`.

**More detail about my target:**

I have a batch of SQL-like data which recorded the user's selection criteria.

> gender = MAN and sports in (football, baseball)

My target is to build a k nearest neighbors to search/predict the user's selection criteria based on what he inputted now.

> Current User input: gender = MAN and sports in (football)

> System recommend: gender = MAN and sports in (football, baseball)

And current result is interesting, some query is able to find some similar query, but those include specials code (e.g. model code) is not able to find. So, I would like to add these model code to the vocab and try will it be better in result.

**My working code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import faiss

#load model
model_name = 'all-MiniLM-L6-v2'
model = SentenceTransformer(model_name)

#load my data
df = pd.read_excel("data/data.xlsx","data")

#embedding my excel data by the model
document_embeddings = model.encode(df['combined'])

#import to faiss
d = document_embeddings.shape[1]
index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(d)
if not (index.is_trained):
    index.train(document_embeddings)
index.add(document_embeddings)

#Find which 10 row in excel is similar to this content
def search_query(input_text, top_k):
    xq = model.encode([input_text])
    D, I = index.search(xq, top_k)

    print(f'Input: {input_text}')
    for i in range(top_k):
        print(f'Similar Content: {df.iloc[I[0][i]]["combined"]}')

search_query("apple is red",10)

#Similar Content: apple is yellow
#Similar Content: banana is red
#etc...
```

**New code, I try to add new vocab to model, but error happend:**

```
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

# for example covid, this is new to world, I think is a good example
new_word = ["Covid-19"]

# check if the tokens are already in the vocabulary
new_tokens = set(new_tokens) - set(tokenizer.vocab.keys())

# add the tokens to the tokenizer vocabulary
tokenizer.add_tokens(list(new_tokens))

# add new, random embeddings for the new tokens
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

#load my data
df = pd.read_excel("data/data.xlsx","data")
#embedding my excel data by the model <------------------------Error happend: AttributeError: 'BertModel' object has no attribute 'encode'
document_embeddings = model.encode(df['combined'])

#import to faiss ............
```

I believed that I have already add `"Covid-19"` in the model. But how can I

1. using this new model to encode?
2. save this new model for future use?
3. how many new vocab can I add? if excess the limit, what will be the solution?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I think there is a conceptual problem with what you are trying to do. That model does not use a word-level vocabulary, but a subword-level vocabulary; this means that it does not need to add new words, because it can represent unseen words by splitting them; furthermore, adding new tokens to the vocabulary is useless unless you retrain the model.

Comment: See section 2 from https://aclanthology.org/2023.americasnlp-1.18 , that might help

Comment: @noe What I am trying to do is I have a batch of SQL-like data which recorded the user's selection criteria. My target is to build a k nearest neighbors to search/predict the user's selection criteria based on what he inputted now. And current result is interesting, some query is able to find some similar query, but those include specials code (e.g. model code) is not able to find. So, I would like to add these model code to the vocab and try will it be better in result.

Answer (score 0):

**First, as mentioned by noe, just adding new words to the tokenizer without retraining the model is useless.**

### However, to answer your questions:

The `encode` method is a method of SentenceTransformer and does not exist in AutoModel. Instead, use the methods of AutoModel.

```
# Tokenize sentences
encoded_input = tokenizer(sentences, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')

# Compute token embeddings
with torch.no_grad():
    model_output = model(**encoded_input)

# Perform pooling
sentence_embeddings = mean_pooling(model_output, 
encoded_input['attention_mask'])

# Normalize embeddings
sentence_embeddings = F.normalize(sentence_embeddings, p=2, dim=1)
```

You will need to **fine-tune the model** on a large enough corpus that uses these words so that the model learns to 'understand' them. You can have a look at [this tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training).

You can **save the model** after training by setting the argument.

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer")
```

Comment: Thanks. The link is broken. Could you update it?